# How to make CSS (or JS?) hideable help bar

Tags: css, notification-bar

Sort of how this website shows a bar on top when you have new answers or comments, I want to show a very similar bar that just has a line of text in it and an [X] to close it. How would I begin to do this?

Comment: Whenever I want a user to be able to hide a message I use jquery, but are you asking how to add the message aswell or just hide one you already have?

If you already have the code for the rest of the page post it up in your question so we can help with a more in depth answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is how you can create it :)](http://jsbin.com/evite4/5)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply keep a div with the position of your wish and use CSS for hiding the same. Whenever you need to show something, set the text inside and set the CSS to show the same. Upon clicking the [X], the CSS can be reset.